# Updating a listox Item value programatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a list box which has some items. I need to concatenate the listbox selected item value with a string when a button is clicked in the form. How can i achive this result.

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (lstItemCode.SelectedItem.ToString().Contains("Complete"))
        {
            lstItemCode.Text = lstItemCode.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("Complete", string.Empty).Trim();
        }
        //else
        //{

        //}
    }
```

Comment: can we see what you have tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have filled your listbox with strings and not with some kind of DataSource (tables, List...) then you could change your SelectedItem line n this way

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(lstItemCode.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string newText = lstItemCode
                            .SelectedItem
                            .ToString()
                            .Replace("Complete", string.Empty)
                            .Trim();
        lstItemCode.Items[lstItemCode.SelectedIndex] = newText;
    }
}
```

The intiial check for null is necessary in case you click the button without any selected item. Finally you reach the current selected item text using the Items collection and retrieving the index of the current selected item

Comment: working partially but values not getting added to the control actually

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you're trying to achieve in your click event:

```
if (lstItemCode.SelectedItem == null)
    return;

if (lstItemCode.SelectedItem.ToString().Contains("Complete"))
{
    int idx = lstItemCode.Items.IndexOf(lstItemCode.SelectedItem);

    if(idx != -1)
        lstItemCode.Items[idx] = lstItemCode.SelectedItem.ToString().Replace("Complete", string.Empty).Trim();
}
```